# Can Corda nodes share a single float?

Tags: corda

Corda Enterprise is expected to include a proxy, also known as a float.

If an organization hosts multiple Corda nodes on an internal network, representing different legal entities, should each node have its own, dedicated float or can nodes share a single float (or a single HA pool of floats)? If so, what are the pros and cons to doing so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each node must have its own float. A single host (server/VM) can host multiple nodes and floats, but a single float is bound to a single node.